# Use of Jmeter for api load testing with full workflow

Tags: jmeter, api-testing

i am using jmeter for api load testing  but i face one problem that i need to do load testing for full website with full workflow ,having little idea how to test but it didn't work for full workflow,please do just me how to do api loading testing using jmeter.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do: load test a full workflow through an API? Load test a full workflow through a website that uses the API? What problems are you having? Please edit your question to provide this information.

Answer (score 4):

The idea of the load testing is simulating application **real** usage.

Imagine that each JMeter thread is a real user and design your test in this way so each JMeter's virtual user would act like a real user, for instance:

- Open login page
- Wait until page is loaded
- Locate credentials input
- Type username and password
- Click login button
- Wait until home page is loaded
- Search for something
- Go make some tea
- Return and click on a search result
- etc.

In general you should be acting like:

1. Record your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. If you have more than one test scenarios - repeat step 1 for each. Make sure you put different groups of real users into different JMeter [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
3. Perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) if required.
4. Perform [parameterization](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#parameterising_tests) if required
5. Run the test with 1-2 users/loops and inspect request and response details in View Results Tree listener to ensure your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing
6. [Add more virtual users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)
7. Run your test
8. Analyse results using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)